# How to monitor the EC2 compute usage of a directory on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I've been searching for details of this all day and cannot find any information. I'm using AWS and wanted to know if it is possible, with an amazon service or external, to monitor and log the EC2 compute usage of individual directories?

Comment: This question is pretty similar to a question from yesterday. Did datasage cover it for you? Are you looking for a different method or detail from what he suggested?

Comment: This is specifically about the EC2 compute usage of a directory. I've been looking at the CloudWatch and CloudAbility documentation and they don't mention if you can see that specific data. Was hoping someone would know if those services or others had that feature.

Comment: The closest you could get to this is if you dedicate an instance to each customer. You may be able to in some cases determine how much CPU goes to each customer's application, but it would depend on the application/stack. You may also consider tracking credits based on certain actions. For example, a base operation cost might be 1 credit, but a high cpu operation might be 3-5 credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to allocate Amazon EC2 usage costs to a fine-grained level, such as individual directory, application or user.

**Amazon EC2 is charged on an hourly basis**, with the cost varying by:

- [Instance Type](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) (CPU, RAM, chipset)
- Operating System (eg Windows instances include an hourly charge for Windows)
- Billing type (On-Demand, Reserved Instance, Spot)

While the AWS billing system can allocate EC2 costs based on **tags** (eg Department), this is only done for a whole instance on an hourly basis.

Some ideas for fine-grained allocation of costs:

- Record usage in CloudWatch via a Custom Metric, then extract data for billing purposes
- Store usage information in log files and send them to CloudWatch Logs, then extra data for billing purposes
- Track usage in a file, send it to Amazon S3 and then aggregate information each billing cycle

Each of these options would require custom coding and processing.